# Django Wagtail: get children of page using custom method in django regular view

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

I am playing with **Wagtail 2.6.1** and I got in confusing problem. I need to work with Page model in vanilla Django view. I want to get children of BlogPage, so I made custom method, which should return all children pages. Method works, but only in template view. When I access it in django view, it returns empty queryset. I really don't understand why.

**My models.py**

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    template = "blog/blog.html"
    max_count = 1    
    subpage_types = ['blog.BlogPostPage','blog.PostAdvancedPage']        

    promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
       FieldPanel('menu_order'),
   ]

    def getChildren(self):
        children = self.get_children().live().all()        
        return children

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(BlogPage, self).get_context(request)
        context['categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.order_by('name').all() 
        context['blog_posts'] = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at').all()            
        return context

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blogs"
```

**my views.py**

```
from .models import BlogPage

def post_filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':      

        posts = BlogPage().getChildren() # this return empty queryset
        print (posts)
```

**but when I render this method in template blog.html it works:**

```
<div class="section py-9">
  {{self.getChildren}}
</div>
```

it successfully render all children pages in template:

```
<PageQuerySet [<Page: Lorem Ipsum 01>,<Page: Lorem Ipsum 02>]>
```

Please note that I am normally using get_context method to render all posts in my template, I just tried render this method (getChildren) in template to check if that's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `BlogPage().getChildren()` means "create a new `BlogPage` instance in memory, and fetch its children". Naturally, since it's only just been created, it won't have any child pages, and so this returns an empty queryset.

For the `post_filter` view to do something useful, you'll need to specify an existing `BlogPage` instance for it to call `getChildren` on. You haven't mentioned how `post_filter` is going to be used, so I don't know where this information should come from - but one possibility is to pass it as a parameter in the URL, in which case `post_filter` will look like this:

```
def post_filter(request, page_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        posts = BlogPage.objects.get(id=page_id).getChildren()
        print (posts)
```

Comment: Hello Gasman, thank you very much this is result of brainfog after several days of struggling with wagtail project. I made here basic python mistake. You are right I am creating new object :( Thank you very much for pointing me to right direction.